# Why does YouTube fullscreen no longer work in Firefox if I customize the user agent string?

Tags: youtube, firefox

I'm asking this question mostly out of curiosity as it probably has little practical value.

I've noticed that if I change the user agent string for my Firefox browser using `about:config` -> `general.useragent.override`, fullscreen on YouTube no longer works. Initially, I thought it was because I used the useragent string of MS Edge which maybe somehow doesn't support it, but I've later used IE11's and verified that fullscreen works fine in that browser.

So, the current user agent I'm using is this:
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko`

This is what YT's toolbar looks like for me:

[image]

I'm using the latest version of Firefox - `44.0.2` at the moment of writing - on Windows 8.1 Pro x64. Of course, without the user agent override, this feature works properly.

**What is the reason for this behavior?**

Comment: It may be that YouTube is trying to use edge-specific commands (like you have in css the `-moz`, `-webkit` and `-ms` prefixed elements), which it then finds aren't available in your browser, so it gives you an error.